# Crystal Report 10.5 (VS2008) can work with VS2010?

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-export

Can I use Crystal Report 10.5 of VS2008 with VS2010?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I have worked out no in terms of you can't use the designer and it won't generate the .cs files for any reports you add to the project. However you can compile and run any existing stuff.

A way to work around this is maintain a VS 2008 solution file pointing to the same projects. Loading them up in vs 2008 whenever you need to edit or create new reports. Then switch back to vs 2010 when doing anything else once the .cs files behind the reports are built and editing is done.

Also  crystal reports for vs 2010 I believe is out but doesn't come with it anymore.